# Jquery specific id article content does not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My plan:

A menu-items (hooked to articles within my content division). Initially all the articles are hidden. But when a menu-item is selected, the content-division should show only the article corresponding with the hit menu-item. Same story for the other menu-items.

I am new to JS. I cannot figure out why the separate articles won't show. The first function of hiding everything initially works though.

**my html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Hartmeting</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header id="titel">
                <h1>Heartmeasurement</h1>
            </header>

            <!-- Menu -->
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#menu_a">Introduction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu_b">The Problem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu_c">The Manual</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu_c">Measuring the heart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- The Articles -->
            <div id="content">
                <!-- Intro Article -->
                <article id="menu_a">
                    <h2>Introduction</h2>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Intro img"/>
                    </figure>
                    <p> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>
                </article>

                <!-- Article 1 -->
                <article id="menu_b">
                    <h2>The Problem</h2>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="First img"/>
                    </figure>
                    <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>
                </article>

                <!-- Article 2 -->
                <article id="menu_c">
                    <h2>The Manual</h2>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Second Article"/>
                    </figure>
                    <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>
                </article>

                <!-- Article 3 -->  
                <article id="menu_d">
                    <h2>Measuring Your Heart</h2>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Third img"/>
                    </figure>
                    <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>
                </article>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <a href="#wrapper"> To the Top </a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My js code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#content').hide();
});

var visible = $('#menu_a').first();
//visible.show();  this was a test and it did NOT work!!!!!!

var show_me = function(article){
    visible.hide();
    visible = article;
    visible.show();
}

$("#menu_a").click(function(event) {
    var id_of_article = $(this).attr('href');
    var the_article = $(id_of_article);
    show_me(the_article);
    even.preventDefault();
});
```

Why does this not work?  Console doesn't show any errors.

Maybe because every article is within the 'content' id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS solution from previous answer is really nice, but if you want to use jQuery, here is jQuery version.

You have over-complicated this, and yes - one of main problems is that your content/container, which keeep articles, is always hidden. To solve this, hide articles rather:

```
article {
  display:none;
}
```

And simplified JQuery:

```
$("#menu ul li a").click(function() {

var id_of_article = $(this).attr('href');
$('article').not($(id_of_article)).hide();
 $(id_of_article).show();

even.preventDefault();


});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7kd16e1b/1/

Comment: Very neat solution. I tried the jsfiddle worked very well. If I try it in my own code it does not work. this is exactly what my code looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/7kd16e1b/6/  (it does hide the article elements) but it does not hide/show articles per click.

Comment: I fixed it by putting the 2 <script> elements containing the jquery library and my js code at the end of the body element. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user7186935, np, glad to help! (didn't realized what's wrong, when i've seen your working fiddle). Btw, in jsfiddle, jquery is executed on load, by default - so there is no point to write doc.ready wrapper...

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no reason to use JS for this.

You can do this just using CSS:

(Oh, and btw, the reason your js is not working is because you hide the whole parent container, then try to show stuff inside the hidden container). That would be fairly obvious if you looked at your browser's dev-tools while clicking the links in the menu)

```css
article {
  display: none;
  }
[id^=menu_]:target {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
                <header id="titel">
                    <h1>Heartmeasurement</h1>
                </header>

                        <!-- Menu -->
                        <nav id="menu">
                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#menu_a">Introduction</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu_b">The Problem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu_c">The Manual</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu_c">Measuring the heart</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        </nav>

                            <!-- The Articles -->
                            <div id="content">

                                    <!-- Intro Article -->
                                    <article id="menu_a">
                                        <h2>Introduction</h2>
                                            <figure>
                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Intro img"/>
                                            </figure>
                                            <p> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>
                                    </article>

                                    <!-- Article 1 -->

                                    <article id="menu_b">
                                        <h2>The Problem</h2>
                                            <figure>
                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="First img"/>
                                            </figure>
                                            <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>
                                    </article>

                                    <!-- Article 2 -->

                                    <article id="menu_c">
                                        <h2>The Manual</h2>
                                            <figure>
                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Second Article"/>
                                            </figure>
                                            <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>
                                    </article>

                                    <!-- Article 3 -->  

                                    <article id="menu_d">

                                        <h2>Measuring Your Heart</h2>
                                            <figure>
                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Third img"/>
                                            </figure>
                                            <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...</p>

                                    </article>

                            </div>

                <footer>
                    <a href="#wrapper"> To the Top </a>
                </footer>

            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to stick with js because I am trying to learn js.